# How to hide API routes in Next JS frontend

Tags: next.js13, vercel

I have made a NextJS application I want to protect/hide their `/api` routes as any user can access API routes just by typing `URL/api/**/*`. This is a security issue, I am using those API(s) in my app as backend.

I want to hide `/api` route from user so that no one can access that route from front end.

Comment: Even if you "hide" the URL, users would still be able to access the URL's - This shouldn't be a problem with the proper authentication/authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent unauthorized access to the routes you can implement an authentication mechanism to protect them. [Next Auth](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/introduction) is a good choice or use middleware to intercept the requests.